# MongoDB multiple lookup on same collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I have a child collection which has 3 different fields linked to the same master collection. If I merge them into root element 3rd one overwrite first 2, which make sense as all three 3 lookup refers to the same collection. If I do not merge these collections, I need to iterate through the result set and populate model field one by one on the client side, which I want to avoid.

Is there a way, I could merge all 3 lookup result and somehow could change the field name, so one did not override to other.

Below is my code:-

```
module.exports.getAssignmentByClient = function(req, res) {
var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;

Assignment.aggregate([
    {
        $match : 
        { 
            clientId: 4, 
        } , 
    },
    {
       $lookup:
        {
            from: "staffs",
            localField: "assignedMember1",
            foreignField: "staffId",
            as: "member1"
        },            
    },
    {
        $lookup:
         {
             from: "staffs",
             localField: "assignedMember2",
             foreignField: "staffId",
             as: "member2"
         },            
    },
    {
        $lookup:
         {
             from: "staffs",
             localField: "assignedLeader",
             foreignField: "staffId",
             as: "leader"
         },            
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: 
        { 
            newRoot: 
            { 
                $mergeObjects: [ 
                    {$arrayElemAt: [ "$member1", 0 ]}, 
                    {$arrayElemAt: [ "$member2", 0 ]}, 
                    {$arrayElemAt: [ "$leader", 0 ]}, 
                "$$ROOT" ] 
            } 
        }
    }, 
    { 
        $project: 
        { 
            member1: 0,
            member2: 0,
            leader: 0
        } 
    } 
  ],
  function (err, response) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!response) {
        res.status(200).json({ success: false, message: 'Somthing went wrong. Please contact admin.'});
    }
    else {
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Successfull', data: response});
    }
  });
};
```

**Result set without merge:**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Successfull",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5b5d083cf7edf20be8999746",
            "assignmentId": 25,
            "taskId": 1,
            "assignedLeader": 2,
            "assignedMember1": 1,
            "assignedMember2": 1,
            "priority": "M",
            "startDate": "2018-01-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "endDate": "2018-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "R",
            "billingMode": "F",
            "fixedAmount": 12,
            "hourlyRate": 0,
            "hours": 0,
            "hourlyAmount": 0,
            "clientId": 4,
            "__v": 0,
            "member1": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b5906a66a6c614f8cb9bd99",
                    "staffId": 1,
                    "staffName": "A",
                    "designation": "E",
                    "phone": 9876,
                    "address1": "US",
                    "address2": "",
                    "email": "a@a.com",
                    "manager": "2",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],
            "member2": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b5906a66a6c614f8cb9bd99",
                    "staffId": 1,
                    "staffName": "B",
                    "designation": "E",
                    "phone": 9876,
                    "address1": "US",
                    "address2": "",
                    "email": "b@b.com",
                    "manager": "2",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],
            "leader": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b5906cb6a6c614f8cb9bd9a",
                    "staffId": 2,
                    "staffName": "C",
                    "designation": "M",
                    "phone": 2488263783,
                    "address1": "U",
                    "address2": "",
                    "email": "c@c.com",
                    "manager": "",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**ResultSet with merge:- [The Last lookup with leader replace member 1 and member 2]**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Successfull",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5b5d083cf7edf20be8999746",
            "assignmentId": 25,
            "taskId": 1,
            "assignedLeader": 2,
            "assignedMember1": 1,
            "assignedMember2": 1,
            "priority": "M",
            "startDate": "2018-01-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "endDate": "2018-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "R",
            "billingMode": "F",
            "fixedAmount": 12,
            "hourlyRate": 0,
            "hours": 0,
            "hourlyAmount": 0,
            "clientId": 4,
            "__v": 0,
            "staffId": 2,
            "staffName": "C",
            "designation": "M",
            "phone": 2488263783,
            "address1": "U",
            "address2": "",
            "email": "c@c.com",
            "manager": "",
        }
    ]
}
```

**Updated Code:-**

```
module.exports.getAssignmentByClient = function(req, res) {
var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;

Assignment.aggregate([
    {
        $match : 
        { 
            clientId: 4, 
        } , 
    },
    {
       $lookup:
        {
            from: "staffs",
            localField: "assignedMember1",
            foreignField: "staffId",
            as: "member1"
        },            
    },
    {
        $lookup:
         {
             from: "staffs",
             localField: "assignedMember2",
             foreignField: "staffId",
             as: "member2"
         },            
    },
    {
        $lookup:
         {
             from: "staffs",
             localField: "assignedLeader",
             foreignField: "staffId",
             as: "leader"
         },            
    },
    {"$replaceRoot":{
        "newRoot":{
          "$reduce":{
            "input":[{"k":"member1","v":"$member1"},{"k":"member2","v":"$member2"},{"k":"leader","v":"$leader"}],
            "initialValue":"$$ROOT",
            "in":{
              "$mergeObjects":[
                {"$let":{
                  "vars":{"v":{"$arrayElemAt":["$$this.v",0]}},
                  "in":{"$arrayToObject":{
                    "$map":{
                      "input":{"$objectToArray":"$$v"},
                      "as":"val",
                      "in":{
                        "k":{"$concat":["$$this.k","-","$$val.k"]},
                        "v":"$$val.v"}
                    }
                  }}
                }},
                "$$value"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
    }},
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "member1": 0, 
            "member2": 0, 
            "leader": 0 
        } 
    } 
  ],
  function (err, response) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!response) {
        res.status(200).json({ success: false, message: 'Somthing went wrong. Please contact admin.'});
    }
    else {
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Successfull', data: response});
    }
  });
```

};

JSON Result with updated code:-

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "Successfull",
"data": [
    {
        "leader-_id": "5b5906cb6a6c614f8cb9bd9a",
        "leader-staffId": 2,
        "leader-staffName": "A",
        "leader-designation": "M",
        "leader-phone": 2488263783,
        "leader-address1": "US",
        "leader-address2": "",
        "leader-email": "a@a.com",
        "leader-manager": "",
        "leader-__v": 0,
        "member2-_id": "5b5906a66a6c614f8cb9bd99",
        "member2-staffId": 1,
        "member2-staffName": "B",
        "member2-designation": "E",
        "member2-phone": 9876,
        "member2-address1": "US",
        "member2-address2": "",
        "member2-email": "b@b.com",
        "member2-manager": "2",
        "member2-__v": 0,
        "member1-_id": "5b5906a66a6c614f8cb9bd99",
        "member1-staffId": 1,
        "member1-staffName": "C",
        "member1-designation": "E",
        "member1-phone": 9876,
        "member1-address1": "US",
        "member1-address2": "",
        "member1-email": "c@c.com",
        "member1-manager": "2",
        "member1-__v": 0,
        "_id": "5b5d083cf7edf20be8999746",
        "assignmentId": 25,
        "taskId": 1,
        "assignedLeader": 2,
        "assignedMember1": 1,
        "assignedMember2": 1,
        "priority": "M",
        "startDate": "2018-01-08T05:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2018-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
        "status": "R",
        "billingMode": "F",
        "fixedAmount": 12,
        "hourlyRate": 0,
        "hours": 0,
        "hourlyAmount": 0,
        "clientId": 4,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b5e0f9ced856f17187c8888",
        "assignmentId": 28,
        "taskId": 2,
        "assignedLeader": "2",
        "assignedMember1": "1",
        "assignedMember2": "1",
        "priority": "H",
        "startDate": "2018-01-08T05:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2018-07-08T04:00:00.000Z",
        "status": "C",
        "billingMode": "F",
        "fixedAmount": 900,
        "hourlyRate": 0,
        "hours": 0,
        "hourlyAmount": 0,
        "clientId": 4,
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

}

**Nested collection field reference *** (I have nested lookup for assignmentMaster and then I want to refer this collection field into some other collection as match field but it's not returning the desired result. Seems like I am not able to refer assignmentMaster field correctly.)

```
module.exports.getAssignmentByClient = function(req, res) {
var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
var clientId = parseInt(query.clientId);

AssignmentDetail.aggregate([
    {
        $match : 
        { 
            clientId: clientId, 
        } , 
    },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "assignmentmasters",
            localField: "assignmentId",
            foreignField: "assignmentId",
            as: "assignmentMasterData"
        },            
    },
    { 
        $lookup: {
        from: "lists",
        let: { "status": "$assignmentMasterData" },
        pipeline: [
            { 
                $match: 
                    { $expr: { $and: [ 
                        { $eq: 
                            [ "$listName", "AssignmentStatus" ] 
                        },
                        { $eq: 
                            [ "$listItem", "$$status.status" ] 
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                } 
            },
        ],
        as: "assignmentStatus"
    }},


    {"$replaceRoot":{
        "newRoot":{
          "$reduce":{
            "input":[{"k":"assignmentStatus","v":"$assignmentStatus"},{"k":"assignmentMasterData","v":"$assignmentMasterData"}],
            "initialValue":"$$ROOT",
            "in":{
              "$mergeObjects":[
                {"$let":{
                  "vars":{"v":{"$arrayElemAt":["$$this.v",0]}},
                  "in":{"$arrayToObject":{
                    "$map":{
                      "input":{"$objectToArray":"$$v"},
                      "as":"val",
                      "in":{
                        "k":{"$concat":["$$this.k","-","$$val.k"]},
                        "v":"$$val.v"}
                    }
                  }}
                }},
                "$$value"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
    }},
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "assignmentStatus": 0,
            "assignmentMasterData": 0
        } 
    } 
  ],
  function (err, response) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!response) {
        res.status(200).json({ success: false, message: 'Somthing went wrong. Please contact admin.'});
    }
    else {
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Successfull', data: response});
    }
  });
```

};

Comment: can you post sample document from all the collections... and what is your mongodb version?

Comment: I updated my question with the result set. Mongo DB version is 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query to prefix all the keys of each lookup with its alias.

Use [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) to prefix the lookup alias to each of the looked up column using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) & [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operator.

Example shown below for member1. Add all the other look up alias similarly.

Something like

```
{"$replaceRoot":{
    "newRoot":{
      "$mergeObjects":[
        {"$let":{
          "vars":{"v":{"$arrayElemAt":["$member1",0]}},
          "in":{"$arrayToObject":{
            "$map":{
                "input":{"$objectToArray":"$$v"},
                "as":"val",
                "in":{
                  "k":{"$concat":["member1","-","$$val.k"]},
                  "v":"$$val.v"
                }}
          }}
        }},
       --- other look up alias here 
      ]
   }
}}
```

If you don't want to repeat the same code for all alias you can create a array of  documents and `$reduce` to create the merged documents.

Something like

```
{"$replaceRoot":{
  "newRoot":{
    "$reduce":{
      "input":[{"k":"member1","v":"$member1"},{"k":"member2","v":"$member2"},{"k":"leader","v":"$leader"}],
      "initialValue":"$$ROOT",
      "in":{
        "$mergeObjects":[
          {"$let":{
            "vars":{"v":{"$arrayElemAt":["$$this.v",0]}},
            "in":{"$arrayToObject":{
              "$map":{
                "input":{"$objectToArray":"$$v"},
                "as":"val",
                "in":{
                  "k":{"$concat":["$$this.k","-","$$val.k"]},
                  "v":"$$val.v"}
              }
            }}
          }},
          "$$value"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: It works when I have only one record in the collection Assignment. If the collection has one record it works and replaces field name with member 1, 2 and leader lookup. but if a collection has more than one record, it doesn't concat lookup result.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. As I understand  concatenate all looked up record for each assignment row. So in case of multiple assignment rows you should get multiple concatenated rows. Is that not what you want ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. For each assignment row, I want to concatenate result from the lookup. Right now it working fine for the first row from the assignment but rest of the rows from Assignment not having any concatenated rows from the lookup.

Comment: That shouldn't have happened. Is there any chance I can look at your query ? May be add to the bottom of the post ?

Comment: I have updated the code with tag Updated Code. Please have a look and thanks for looking into this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Your code looks good. Can you try running the code in mongo shell ?

Comment: I see the issue. Your local fields type for second assignment row  is string. You have to change that to number for lookup to work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. It works. Really sorry. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: One question for you, If you can help me. In below code client number variable remains undefined inside aggregate. Any idea.

module.exports.getAssignmentByClient = function(req, res) {
 var clientNumber = 4.

Assignment.aggregate([
    {
        $match : 
        { 
            clientId: clientNumber, 
        } , 
    },
 ]);

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry, I don't know mongoose/JavaScript. Feel free to create new question.

Comment: Just curious. my answer didn't work for you ? I thought it did.

Comment: Hey, I have one more issue with this task. I have updated the code with the title 'Nested collection field reference'. Could you please help me with this. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Please create a separate question if you could. I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: Veeram, I have added a separate question with the title 'MongoDB nested lookup'. Please have a look and thanks for your time.!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way, I could merge all 3 lookup result and somehow could change the field name, so one did not override to other.

You can concat arrays using **$concatArrays** in your existing query (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) of aggregation!

Try this code:

```
module.exports.getAssignmentByClient = function(req, res) {
var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;

Assignment.aggregate([
    {
        $match : 
        { 
            clientId: 4, 
        } , 
    },
    {
       $lookup:
        {
            from: "staffs",
            localField: "assignedMember1",
            foreignField: "staffId",
            as: "member1"
        },            
    },
    {
        $lookup:
         {
             from: "staffs",
             localField: "assignedMember2",
             foreignField: "staffId",
             as: "member2"
         },            
    },
    {
        $lookup:
         {
             from: "staffs",
             localField: "assignedLeader",
             foreignField: "staffId",
             as: "leader"
         },            
    },
    { 
        $project: { 
            items: { 
                $concatArrays: [ "$member1", "$member2", "$leader" ] 
            } 
        } 
    }
  ],
  function (err, response) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!response) {
        res.status(200).json({ success: false, message: 'Somthing went wrong. Please contact admin.'});
    }
    else {
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Successfull', data: response});
    }
  });
};
```

***Hope this solves your query!***

Comment: It works but again it added all the lookup result in the new array i.e., item, not into the root. I was looking to add all lookup result into the root only. Thanks for your reply and looking into it.